# OAuth authentication with EWS Managed API applications for a specific mailbox

Tags: azure, security, exchangewebservices, azure-oauth

We changed our application such that it authenticates an EWS application by using OAuth. The article [«Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth»](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) was of great help.

The subsection «**Configure for app-only authentication**» describes how to give permissions by replacing the requiredResourceAccess property in the *manifest* with an example JSON:

```
{
    "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
    "resourceAccess": [
        {
            "id": "dc890d15-9560-4a4c-9b7f-a736ec74ec40",
            "type": "Role"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this gives *full_access_as_app* to *all* mailboxes in the company.
[image]
And we would like to limit the app's access to a specific mailbox.
How can we adjust this example JSON?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: [Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)